# Compare two array list using O(logn) complexity in java

Tags: java

```
ArrayList<String> array1 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("netflix", "dhoni", "harini", "obama", "machintosh"));

ArrayList<String> array2 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("netflix", "dhoni", "harini", "obama", "quark", "machintosh"));
```

We have to array list with same string and same order but in array2 one string is different. I have to find out that string and its position using O(LogN) complexity.

I have solved using O(N) complexity but I want O(LogN) complexity.

My Solution is given below:-

```
ArrayList<String> array1 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("netflix", "dhoni", "harini", "obama", "machintosh"));
ArrayList<String> array2 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("netflix", "dhoni", "harini", "obama", "quark", "machintosh"));
for(int i = 1; i <= array2.size(); i++){
    if(array1.contains(array2.get(i-1))){

    }
    else{
        System.out.println(array2.get(i-1)+" "+i);
    }
}
```

But its giving O(N) complexity.

Comment: I don't think its possible with an ArrayList

Comment: Do you think a logn solution exists?

Comment: Not possible. You need to check all the elements. The complexity of what you've given is O(n*m) because `ArrayList.contains` must do a linear search. You can improve to O(n) if one or both collections is a `Set`, or O(n * log m) if one of the collections is sorted (with a binary search)

Comment: If you have discovered such an algorithm, congratulations, you have proved that `P=NP`

Comment: @Meini With any other list then?

Comment: Continuing , in this case element search in any array would be O(logn)

Comment: If _"one string is different"_ is unconstrained, this task is impossible and you need to check all elements. If the lists are specified to be exactly equal and the "change" is specified to always be "there's an extra element" or "there's a missing element" or something similarly specific, you could use a binary search to find the first index of a difference.

Comment: I think Petr's comment is the key here. If the only allowed change is to have one extra element (or one missing element), then it *can* be done in O(log N) and, @user7, no it doesn't need to be sorted.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException Can you expand further how you can do a binary search if the lists are not sorted?

Comment: @user7 it's not required to do search based on content. It's only required to search based on equality (or otherwise) between element n in list1 and element n in list2.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException In O(log N)?How?

Comment: @user7 as per my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that works with lists of any class (as long as its `equals` method does the right thing).

```
package so53375733;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list1 = Arrays.asList("netflix", "dhoni", "harini", "obama", "machintosh");
        List<String> list2 = Arrays.asList("netflix", "dhoni", "harini", "obama", "quark", "machintosh");
        int addedElementIndex = findAddedElement(list1, list2);
        System.out.printf(
                "Found difference at index %1$d:%n" +
                        "list1[%1$d] = \"%2$s\"%n" +
                        "list2[%1$d] = \"%3$s\"%n",
                addedElementIndex,
                addedElementIndex < list1.size() ? list1.get(addedElementIndex) : "[end of list]",
                addedElementIndex < list2.size() ? list2.get(addedElementIndex) : "[end of list]");
    }

    /**
     * Performs a binary search for an added (or removed) element of list1 with respect to list2
     * (or vice versa). The lists passed as argument should differ only by the addition of one element,
     * so that their sizes differ by 1 and the lists are identical except for the extra element in one
     * of the lists. If the lists are random-access (i.e. directly indexable in O(1) time) then this
     * method's time complexity is O(log N).
     * @param list1 A random-access list
     * @param list2 A random-access list
     * @return The index of the extra element
     */
    private static <T> int findAddedElement(List<T> list1, List<T> list2) {
        int low = 0;
        int high = Math.min(list1.size(), list2.size()) - 1;

        if (list1.get(high).equals(list2.get(high)))
            return high + 1;

        // Loop invariants:
        // 1. Elements of list1 are equal to those of list2 at all indices less than 'low'.
        // 2. Elements of list1 are NOT equal to those of list2 at all indices >= 'high'.
        while (low < high) {
            int mid = (low + high) >>> 1;  // (low+high)/2 might overflow
            if (list1.get(mid).equals(list2.get(mid)))
                low = mid + 1;
            else
                high = mid;
        }

        return low;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Found difference at index 4:
list1[4] = "machintosh"
list2[4] = "quark"
```

Comment: Yup, that's what I had in mind, nicely done. For full correctness it's worth saying that `(low + high) / 2` [can overflow](https://ai.googleblog.com/2006/06/extra-extra-read-all-about-it-nearly.html), so `(low + high) >>> 1` with a comment is preferred.

Comment: I think the second `if` is still needed to handle the case where the inserted element is at the end.

Comment: I don't believe this works. If `list2` is declared as `List<String> list2 = Arrays.asList("netflix", "horse", "harini", "obama", "machintosh");` the output is:
`Found difference at index 5:
list1[5] = "[end of list]"
list2[5] = "[end of list]"`

Comment: @gioaudino as the trail of comments under the question say, it is not possible to do what the question asked in O(log N) time. But then the constraint was mentioned that the only difference is either the addition or a deletion of an element. This answer solves the problem given such a constraint. This is stated in the Javadoc comment for the method `findAddedElement` (and also the method name gives a clue to what it does). Your test data involves only a change in one of the elements, which is a scenario that this method is specifically not intended to cover.

Comment: The question is misleading. What if "my" list had had one addition and one deletion?

Answer (score 1):

You could binary search, like this:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> int findIndexOfNewElement(List<T> list, List<T> modelList) {
    int lower = 0;
    int upper = list.size() - 1;
    int mid = (upper + lower) / 2;
    while (lower < upper) {
        if (mid >= modelList.size()) {
            // The last element is the new one
            return modelList.size();
        }
        if (list.get(mid).compareTo(modelList.get(mid)) != 0) {
            // if they are not the same element
            // then there has been an insert before or at this index
            upper = mid;
        } else {
            lower = mid + 1;
        }
        mid = (upper + lower) / 2;
    }
    return mid;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<String> array1 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("netflix", "dhoni", "harini", "obama", "machintosh"));
    ArrayList<String> array2 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("netflix", "dhoni", "harini", "obama", "quark", "machintosh"));

    int i = findIndexOfNewElement(array2, array1);
    System.out.println(i + " = " + array2.get(i)); // 4 = quark
}
```